# How to get a result from 2 inputs

Tags: java, android

My homework is to make an app, which basically a University Test Grade calculator, everything works except one part.

I have 3 EditText fields: Percentage, Number of questions and Correctly answered a number of questions. In the if-statements I have, it says that if the Percentage you get on your test is within a certain range, for example, <=  100 to > 90. Everything works if I manually put in the Percentage, so 98%, 98 correct answers and it fills the 3rd EditText with 100 total questions.

My problem is when I don't fill in the Percentage, it doesn't work. If I were to fill Total Questions = 100 and Correctly Answered = 98, it would crash the app, since my ifs only contain the EditText input. I don't know what else I could do, any help is appreciated.

I've tried making a new double to int and putting it into the if statement, that if the double Percentage is 0, then it would still set the score right, but that didn't work.

Here it calculates the Percentage from the 2 other inputs

```
double Percentage = 0;
                    if (percentage.length() == 0) {
                        Percentage = 100 * Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswerPoints))
.getText().toString()) / Double.parseDouble(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNrOfQuestions)).getText().toString());
                        percentage.setText(String.format("%.0f", Percentage) + "%");

                    }
```

Then it highlights a table row of the correct grade you get, except it crashes when I leave the Percentage input at 0.

```
int etPercent = Integer.parseInt(percentage.getText().toString());

if (etPercent <= 100 && etPercent > 90) {
                firstRow.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHighlight));
                yourScore.setText("Your score is " + (answerpoints.getText().toString()) + "/" + (numberofquestions.getText().toString() + "\n Your grade is A"));
            }
```

I expect it to work if I were to leave the Percentage input empty.

Thank you.

Comment: *except it crashes* - please post your stacktarce

Answer (score 0):

In the first place you need to read what is a "Clean code"!

- You have too long lines of code. Split them. (Find the view, get the result, format it, then use it)
  EditText answerEditText = findViewById(R.id.answer);
  int answeredNumberOfQuestions = Integer.parseInt(answerEditText.getText().toString());
  handeUserResult(answeredNumberOfQuestions)
- You need to have good names which are consistent and good. Nr is not ok for example. etNrOfQuestions shoud be NumberOfQuestion or number_of_questions.
- Slit the code in meaningful method names. Your code should "tell a story". You need to some abstractions like:

  (ifInRange()){
    handleInRange()
   } else { 
   handleNotInRange()
  }

  - Create a function called formatResult() for example.
- Use constants and do not hardcode values:
  public static final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 100; // I am just guessing here.

  Then when your code looks clean it will be easier for you to know what is the problem. You don't write code for the CPU, you write it for your colleagues!!!

When you have understood what are the input and outputs you will not have such code like:

if (etPercent <= 100 && etPercent > 90)

It does not makes sense the first check: "etPercent <= 100" . How the percent could be above 100? This is a defensive check which is not ok. You should assure that what is giving you the percentage gives you the right result. Than you can make like this:

if(inRange(percentage)) // please create some meaningful name what exactly is the range like: for example isPassedTest()

and the implementation could be:

```
public static final int MINIMUM_PASSING_SCORE= 90;
boolean isPassedTest(int percentage){
   return percentage > MINIMUM_PASSING_SCORE;
}
```

So you will execute:

```
int percentage = getPercentage(maxNumberOfAnswers, studentAnswers);
if(isPassedTest(percentage)){
  notifyStudentSuccess()
} else {
notifyStudentFail()
}
```